# Rearrange unbalanced time series data

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large unbalanced dataset (around 2000 stocks) consisting of return data of shares, and now I want to rearrange the return data, so it all ends up at the same date.

My data look likes this:

```
Date         RF   STOCK-A  STOCK-B  STOCK-C  STOCK-D 
1990-11-30   0,03   0,20    0,30     -0,40     0,90
1990-12-31   0,10   0,30    0,30     -0,40     0,34
1991-01-31   0,12   0,90    0,30     -0,60     0,78
1991-02-28   0,03   0,12    0,30       NA      0,50
1991-03-31   0,04   0,14    0,30       NA      0,12
1991-04-30   0,05   0,18    0,30       NA      0,11
1991-05-31   0,03   0,00     NA        NA       NA
1991-06-30   0,00   0,20     NA        NA       NA
```

My problem is, that I want all the stock returns ending in 1991-06-30 and fill in NA in the early dates instead, so it looks like this:

```
 Date         RF   STOCK-A  STOCK-B  STOCK-C  STOCK-D 
1990-11-30   0,03   0,20     NA    -   NA      NA
1990-12-31   0,10   0,30     NA        NA      NA
1991-01-31   0,12   0,90    0,30       NA     0,90
1991-02-28   0,03   0,12    0,30       NA     0,34
1991-03-31   0,04   0,14    0,30       NA     0,78
1991-04-30   0,05   0,18    0,30     -0,40    0,50
1991-05-31   0,03   0,00    0,30     -0,40    0,12 
1991-06-30   0,00   0,20    0,30     -0,60    0,11
```

I tried using the lag function like this:

```
data2 <- if (any(is.na(data$STOCK-B))==TRUE){
lag(data$STOCK-B, k= -sum(is.na(data$STOCK-B)))
}else {
any(is.na(data$STOCK-B)==FALSE) 
lag(data$STOCK-B, k=0)
}
```

My idea was to implement it in a for loop, but it doesn`t work and simply return a atomic vector.

I find another method with the DataCombine package:

```
 Data1 <- slide(data, Var = "data$STOCK-B", slideBy = -sum(is.na(data$STOCK- 
 B)))
```

It moves the data down as a want, but enter in a new variable to the dataset. Of course, I can use that method and then extract the new variables into a new dataset, but how does this make it more effective?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each column concatenate the NAs with the non-NAs:

```
moveNA <- function(x) c(Filter(is.na, x), na.omit(x))
replace(data, -1, lapply(data[-1], moveNA))
```

giving:

```
        Date   RF STOCK.A STOCK.B STOCK.C STOCK.D
1 1990-11-30 0.03    0.20      NA      NA      NA
2 1990-12-31 0.10    0.30      NA      NA      NA
3 1991-01-31 0.12    0.90     0.3      NA    0.90
4 1991-02-28 0.03    0.12     0.3      NA    0.34
5 1991-03-31 0.04    0.14     0.3      NA    0.78
6 1991-04-30 0.05    0.18     0.3    -0.4    0.50
7 1991-05-31 0.03    0.00     0.3    -0.4    0.12
8 1991-06-30 0.00    0.20     0.3    -0.6    0.11
```

An alternative and even shorter `moveNA` would be:

```
moveNA <- function(x) x[order(!is.na(x))]
```

### Note

The input `data` in reproducible form that was used is:

```
data <-
structure(list(Date = structure(1:8, .Label = c("1990-11-30", 
"1990-12-31", "1991-01-31", "1991-02-28", "1991-03-31", "1991-04-30", 
"1991-05-31", "1991-06-30"), class = "factor"), RF = c(0.03, 
0.1, 0.12, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.03, 0), STOCK.A = c(0.2, 0.3, 
0.9, 0.12, 0.14, 0.18, 0, 0.2), STOCK.B = c(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 
0.3, 0.3, NA, NA), STOCK.C = c(-0.4, -0.4, -0.6, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), STOCK.D = c(0.9, 0.34, 0.78, 0.5, 0.12, 0.11, NA, NA
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can define a function to help sorting, and then use `mutate_at` from the `dplyr` package to sort each column.

```
library(dplyr)

sort_fun <- function(x){
  x_NA <- x[is.na(x)]
  x_non_NA <- x[!is.na(x)]
  x <- c(x_NA, x_non_NA)
  return(x)
}

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-Date), funs(sort_fun(.)))
dat2
#         Date   RF STOCK.A STOCK.B STOCK.C STOCK.D
# 1 1990-11-30 0,03    0,20    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
# 2 1990-12-31 0,10    0,30    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
# 3 1991-01-31 0,12    0,90    0,30    <NA>    0,90
# 4 1991-02-28 0,03    0,12    0,30    <NA>    0,34
# 5 1991-03-31 0,04    0,14    0,30    <NA>    0,78
# 6 1991-04-30 0,05    0,18    0,30   -0,40    0,50
# 7 1991-05-31 0,03    0,00    0,30   -0,40    0,12
# 8 1991-06-30 0,00    0,20    0,30   -0,60    0,11
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "Date         RF   STOCK-A  STOCK-B  STOCK-C  STOCK-D 
1990-11-30   0,03   0,20    0,30     -0,40     0,90
                  1990-12-31   0,10   0,30    0,30     -0,40     0,34
                  1991-01-31   0,12   0,90    0,30     -0,60     0,78
                  1991-02-28   0,03   0,12    0,30       NA      0,50
                  1991-03-31   0,04   0,14    0,30       NA      0,12
                  1991-04-30   0,05   0,18    0,30       NA      0,11
                  1991-05-31   0,03   0,00     NA        NA       NA
                  1991-06-30   0,00   0,20     NA        NA       NA",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `apply` function:

```
apply(data,2,function(x) as.numeric(x[order(!is.na(x))]))
```

**DATA**

```
data <-structure(list(Date = structure(1:8, .Label = c("1990-11-30", 
"1990-12-31", "1991-01-31", "1991-02-28", "1991-03-31", "1991-04-30", 
"1991-05-31", "1991-06-30"), class = "factor"), RF = c(0.03, 
0.1, 0.12, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.03, 0), STOCK.A = c(0.2, 0.3, 
0.9, 0.12, 0.14, 0.18, 0, 0.2), STOCK.B = c(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 
0.3, 0.3, NA, NA), STOCK.C = c(-0.4, -0.4, -0.6, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), STOCK.D = c(0.9, 0.34, 0.78, 0.5, 0.12, 0.11, NA, NA
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```